# ios swift 5 MaterialTextFieldView input test not working

Tags: ios, swift5

ios swift 5 MaterialTextFieldView input test not working now i have already set delegate but .setText("Placeholder") not working please help

Comment: You might want clarify your question because MaterialTextFieldView is no basic class in UIKit. I assume you use some Material Design library and you might want to add a tag with the name of the library to the tags. This way your question is easier found and people can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Please use bellow solution

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tfmName.setMaterial(self, "Placeholder", self)
}
```